# Is it possible to avoid direct reference?

Tags: c#

I have a C# project(project 1) that references another project(project 2).
Project2 is using a certain NuGet package, np1, which is not installed on project 1.
From project 1, I can call any method from project 2 but if I call any function made available by np1, i get an error.
The error is: Could not load file or assembly... from project 2.
I would like to add that np1 is properly installed or referenced on project 2 and works on an "as is" basis.
However, if I also add the np1 to project 1, the code works just fine.
Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: It sounds like np1 is not being copied to the `bin` folder. Have you tried setting the reference to `Copy Local`?

Comment: So you are trying to reference the nuget package directly from the first project, without adding it as a reference to that project? That doesn't work, even though you reference project 2 and project 2 has a reference to the nuget package. You can't reference everything that your referenced project has included in it. Otherwise you create a huge reference mess.

Comment: Yes. Copy to local is set to true for both the following: as project2 reference in project 1 and for np1 rerference in project 2

Comment: @RonBeyer No. I'm calling simple transition methods from project1 to project2. In project2 i have functions that call np1. Not calling directly np1 functions from project1.

Comment: Have you checked the `bin` folder to see if np1's DLL is being copied?

Comment: @JuanR at build, the bin folder contains only the project2 dll file. it does not contain the np1 dll's.

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively sure you marked np1's reference to `Copy Local = True`? I might be wrong but I am pretty sure I've done this in the past and it copies the dependencies.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I don't think he is using the dependency methods directly. I think he is calling a method from some class in `project2` that internally uses the dependency.

Comment: @JuanR Yes. I can confirm, copy to local is set to true. If I build project 1, i have the dll of project 2 in bin. If I build project 2, I have the np1 in the project2's bin folder.

Comment: @RonBeyer correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194392/discussion-between-juanr-and-mb14).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround.
Adding the reference by editing the Post-build event command line:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)\*dll_filename*" 
"$(SolutionDir)*relative_path_of_Project1*\"
)
```